# A question on extension of $Z^{*}$ algebras

Tags: gn.general-topology, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory, extension

A $Z^{*}$ algebra is  a $C^{*}$ algebra which all elements  are(two  sided or equivalently one  sided) zero divisor.

> Are there two $Z^{*}$  algebras $A,B$  such that for every short exact sequence of $C^{*}$  algebras: $$0\to A \to C \to  B \to 0$$  $C$ is a  $Z^{*}$  algebra, too?
>
> In particular is there an extension of $C_{0}(X)$ by itself which is  not  a $Z^{*}$  algebra where $X$ is the  [long line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29)?

This is  already aked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172752/a-question-on-z-algebras) as a comment but we ask it here as  an independent question.

**Edit:When a commutative algebra $A$ is in the form of  $A=C_{0}(X)$, we get a formulation of our question in terms of general topology as follows:**

Assume that $X,Y,Z$ are three **locally compact Hausdorff** spaces. We say that $Z$ is an extension of $X$ by $Y$ if $X$ can be embedded as an open set in $Z$ which remainder is homeomorphic to $Y$. We say that $X$ is approximately sigma compact (briefly A$\sigma$C) if there is  a  sequence of compact sets $K_{n}\subset X$ such that $\bigcup K_{n}$ is dense in $X$. Our question is the following:

> Are there two NON $A\sigma C$ spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that every extension of $X$ by $Y$ is NON $A\sigma C$?

**Remark:** An alternative terminology: "Extension of $Y$ by $X$" can be replaced by "Extension of $X$ by $Y$"